# Is the inductive_set can only express the situation where condition holds, not for that fails?

Tags: isabelle

```
type_synonym ('q,'a) LTS = "('q * 'a set * 'q) set"

inductive LTS_is_reachable :: "('q, 'a) LTS ⇒  ('q * 'q) set ⇒ 'q ⇒ 'a list ⇒ 'q ⇒ bool" for Δ and Δ' where
  LTS_Empty[intro!]: "LTS_is_reachable Δ Δ' q [] q" |
  LTS_Step1: "LTS_is_reachable Δ Δ' q l q'" if "(q, q'') ∈ Δ'" and "LTS_is_reachable Δ Δ' q'' l q'" |
  LTS_Step2[intro!]: "LTS_is_reachable Δ Δ' q (a # w) q'" if "a ∈ σ" and "(q, σ, q'') ∈ Δ" and "LTS_is_reachable Δ Δ' q'' w q'"
```

I have defined a LTS to express a node can reach other node through a path, where Δ means a transtion with condition, and Δ ' means a transtion without condition. And I want to give a lemma to show that if 'p' can not reach 'ε', like "¬ LTS_is_reachable Δ Δ' q x ε", so that add a (q,p) into Δ' also can not hold.

Like the aim lemma：

```
lemma "¬ LTS_is_reachable Δ Δ' q x ε  ⟹ ¬ LTS_is_reachable Δ ({(p,q)} ∪ Δ') p x ε"
```

But it can not hold, here p can be no occure in the transition. I want to know that whether inductive_set can not express the situation fails or not. So Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Could you please elaborate a bit further on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to prove a lemma that LTS_is_reachable is false. Among the difinition of LTS_is_reachable, ('q, 'a) LTS is a labeled transtion, like q -> {a}->p means that q can reach p via a, and ('q * 'q) set is an uncondition transition, like (q, p) means that q can reach p anyway. So that I want to prove a lemma, if node q can not reach node p via list x, the node q' cannot reach node p through x when adding (q', q) into ('q * 'q) set. This is the description of the lemma I wanted, and I don't know how to prove by the inductive_set.

Comment: And In my opinion, if LTS_is_reachable D1 D2 q x p holds, there must exists a path starts from q, ends at p, and every transition of x stored in D1, Like LTS_is_reachable {(a, {v1},b),(b,{v2},c)} {(c,d)} a [v1,v2] d. So that envision such a sition, a extra d2 which is transversed, like (e,f) in above cases, LTS_is_reachable {(a, {v1},b),(b,{v2},c)} ({(e,f)} U {(c,d)}) a [v1,v2] d,  I want to achieve that LTS_is_reachable {(a, {v1},b),(b,{v2},c)} {(c,d)} a [v1,v2] d holds without this extra d2. These two lemma are key important for my project. :(

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I'm not sure what you mean by "how to prove by the inductive_set". `inductive_set` allows for the definition of sets inductively, so how does that fit in the picture?

Comment: Slighly unrelated:  what is the point of `Δ` and `Δ'`? Why not put everything in `Δ` with the condition `True`?

Comment: Because we use LTS_is_reachable in NFA， Δ represent the normal transition, and Δ' is used for ε transition. Δ  is a triple set, and the middle element is a 'a set not boolean. If we put the episilon transition in Δ , like (a, { }, b), the semantic might be not correct.

Comment: Can the inductive_set express the situation fails, like how the inductive_set odd express the number 3 is not odd.

Comment: @HongjianJiang: I think the problem here is that your lemma simply doesn't hold. You can obtain counterexamples using `nitpick`. I'm not an expert in automata theory but I suspect that your lemma might hold only under some specific assumptions.